# Open Image Gallery Android

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I made a camera application and save images in DCIM/Yogyakarta, but I can't open that directory. It can only be opened at DCIM/.

Can anyone tell my why I can't open the directory, and how I can fix it?

```java
public final class FroyoAlbumDirFactory extends AlbumStorageDirFactory {

@Override
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new File(
      Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
      ), 
      albumName
    );
 }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();


    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);

    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir("Yogyakarta");              

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(storageDir),"*/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `getAlbumStorageDir` method with below@

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"/"+ albumName);
     }
```

It require "/" to fetch correct path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but
the gallery still not displayed the picture on DCIM/Yogyakarta..

Comment: It should work, I tested in 2.2. Anyway in which device or tablet you are testing?

Comment: i think like that.., I tested in 2.2 and using S.E Neo V OS.2.3.4